# Simulation of Matlab Code in ARM microprocessor

Tags: matlab, arm, simulation

I want to compute some computational overheads of an algorithm that I have created,but the problem is that most of the simulators-emulators have only C compilers so I can't run the Matlab code.
Any suggestions?

Comment: Did you look here? http://www.mathworks.com/hardware-support/arm.html

Comment: matlab used to export C/C++ code, it doesnt any longer?  what does it export?

Comment: The code has a lot of functions that can't be converted from Matlab Coder